# How to create if conditional statement from string within javascript for loop without using eval()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, eval

I'm trying to create an advance search function to use on a multi-dimensional array of product objects. On the form, the user will have the option of narrowing down product results based on data in several different attributes (e.g. "'price' < 20 && 'country' == 'France'", "region == 'New York' && 'vintage' == '2016' && 'qty > 20"). The data, within variable `data` is formatted as follows:

```
    0:
        name: "Kedem Cream Red Concord"
        appellation: "New York"
        country: "United States"
        price: "10.99"
        primarygrape: "Concord"
        qty: "1" 
        region: "New York"
        regprice: "10.99"
        sku: "230"
        vintage: "NV"
    1:
        name: "Kendall Jackson Vintner's Chardonnay" 
        appellation: "" 
        country: "United States" 
        price: "14.99" 
        primarygrape: "Chardonnay"
        qty: "35" 
        region: "California" 
        regprice: "18.99"
        sku: "345" 
        vintage: "2016"
... continuing on over 10,000 product records
```

I figured I could create a string based on the user form input fairly easily that sums up what they're searching for. However, I need a safe way to evaluate that string within my function that returns the filtered results in `resultsArray`

I was able to get it to work with the `eval()` function, but I know that's not safe or efficient. I also tried fooling around with putting the conditions into an array and trying to incorporate that into the for loop, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. The tricky part is, the conditions could be any number of things involving the following product attributes: **appellation, country, price, primarygrape, qty, region, vintage**. And different attributes use different operators (e.g. country, region, and others use '==' while qty and price use '>' or '<').

This code works, but uses the taboo `eval()` function:

```
var conditional = "data[i].price < 20 && data[i].country == 'France' && data[i].vintage == '2016'";

var resultArray = [];
console.log(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if (eval(conditional))
        {
            resultArray.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, as it results in a `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined` error:

```
var conditional = "return data[i].price < 20 && data[i].country == 'France' && data[i].vintage == '2016'";

var resultArray = [];
console.log(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if (new Function(conditional)())
        {
            resultArray.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to dynamically create that if conditional statement so that it recognizes the `data` variable? Or, is there a better solution?

Comment: `new Function` is probably just as unsafe as `eval()`.

Comment: is your plan to filter an array of datasets?

Comment: @ArayniMax , yes, I'd like to filter the product array (contained in 'data') based on user input.

Comment: How does the user enter the filter? As free text? Or is the text formed from different, controlled inputs (select boxes)?

Comment: @trincot, I haven't actually gotten that far yet, but I was probably going to use selects for country, region, appellation, vintage, and primary grape, with free text for qty, price, and I may also create one for 'name' that's free text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript Arrays have a function called `filter` which can be used to do things like you want to achieve.

For example you have an array with numbers:

`var arr = [1,3,6,2,6]`

And your plan is to filter all even numbers.You can use `array.filter()`. 
you need to pass an anonymous function into it. This function gets called once every entry in which you have access to the current element.
You need to return a boolean in this function - `true` means 
that the element will be in the new, filtered array

Now the completed example to filter all even numbers:

`arr.filter(function(element) {return element%2 == 0})`

I hope that's enough for you to continue. :-) In the next snippet I made a small example with your data array

```js
 var your_data_array = [
 { 
       name: "Kendall Jackson Vintner's Chardonnay",
        appellation: "",
        country: "United States",
        price: "14.99",
        primarygrape: "Chardonnay",
        qty: "35",
        region: "California",
        regprice: "18.99",
        sku: "345",
        vintage: "2016" },
        { 
       name: "Kendall Jackson Vintner's Chardonnay",
        appellation: "",
        country: "United States",
        price: "14.99",
        primarygrape: "Chardonnay",
        qty: "35",
        region: "California",
        regprice: "18.99",
        sku: "345",
        vintage: "2016" },
        { 
       name: "Kendall Jackson Vintner's Chardonnay",
        appellation: "",
        country: "United States",
        price: "14.99",
        primarygrape: "Chardonnay",
        qty: "35",
        region: "California",
        regprice: "18.99",
        sku: "345",
        vintage: "2016" }
 ]
 
 var filtered_array = your_data_array.filter(function(dataElement) {
   return dataElement.country == "United States";
 })
 
 console.log(filtered_array)
```

Comment: Thank you, @ArayniMax! This is perfect. I had tried to use `array.filter()` previously but I think I was having issues getting down to the correct level of the array. This works perfectly, and I know how to move forward now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the conditions based on user input, you can format it how you like, it doesn't need to be a string. I would recommend an array that looks something like this:

```
var conditions = [
  {
    property: 'price',
    comparator: '<',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    property: 'country',
    comparator: '=',
    value: 'France'
  }
];
```

You could then use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to generate your results array:

```
var resultArray = data.filter(function(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
    if (conditions[i].comparator === '=' && 
        item[conditions[i].property] !== conditions[i].value) {
      return false;
    }

    if (conditions[i].comparator === '>' && 
        item[conditions[i].property] <= conditions[i].value) {
      return false;
    }

   if (conditions[i].comparator === '<' && 
        item[conditions[i].property] >= conditions[i].value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This looks like it's the basis for something that could work, but as it's written it doesn't seem to take into account that the data is a multi-dimensional array with several thousand items. So, I'd like to iterate over data to filter out product records. How do I incorporate this piece of my original code to do so: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

Comment: `filter()` does iterate over the array, you can read about it by following the link. Can you clarify how specifically you need to handle multi-dimensional arrays, the example of `data` you provided was not a multi-dimensional array